# Generalization of graph where edges relate more than two vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, hypergraphs

In traditional graph theory, a graph consists of a vertex set $V$ and an edge set $E$, where the elements of $E$ are pairs of vertices from $V$.  Is there a name for "graphs" where the "edges" are triples for instance?   Does this fall under design theory (e.g. Steiner triple system?) or is it called something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ignore the comment from Community.  Your question is perfectly clear.  The term you want is "hypergraph".

Comment: Thank you @saulpatz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you need is [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). Just the main thing is

> A hypergraph is a generalization of a graph in which an edge can join any number of vertices. In contrast, in an ordinary graph, an edge connects exactly two vertices.

[image]